# C++ Publisher and Subscriber in ROS2

Tags: ros2, rviz, c++, publisher, subscribe

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and Ros2 Galactic when I run the code I'm able to get subscribe information and pub this information and also I can see publisher information on topic echo continuously but when I press CTRL + C shut down the code it only publish pose informations once  in the rviz2 but it has to be continuously. Everything seems good I can't understand why this happening.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.hpp"

using std::placeholders::_1;

class MainA : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
  MainA(): Node("main")
{
  gosub_ = this->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>(
    "sol",10,std::bind(&MainA::timer_callback, this,_1));
  publisher_ = this->create_publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>(
    "/checkpoint", 10);
}

private:

void timer_callback(const geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped & msg) const
{
  auto message = geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped();
  message.header.frame_id = "map";
  //message.header.stamp = this->now();
  message.pose.position.x = msg.pose.position.x;
  message.pose.position.y = msg.pose.position.y;
  message.pose.position.z = 0.0;
  

  //std::cout << msg.pose.position.x << std::endl;
  publisher_->publish(message);
}
 rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>::SharedPtr gosub_;
 rclcpp::Publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>::SharedPtr publisher_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
 rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
 rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MainA>());
 rclcpp::shutdown();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your expectation/desire that the node will continue to publish after you shutdown the node with crtl-c? That's how I'm reading it but I guess you mean something else.

Comment: No my code publish always but my robot only take action when I press ctrl-c

Comment: I suggest you add additional information to the question, including what you're trying to do, which nodes are running (paste in the node graph and TF tree) and why you think this particular node is part of the problem. Is this the only node publishing to /checkpoint?

Answer (score 0):

When you Ctrl-C your application, it will no longer be subscribing and publishing. However, rviz2 "may" still be showing the details from the very last publication.

It may be the case that your node and topic have not yet been removed from the DDS layer, even though you terminated your application. Try this:

Ctrl-C your application then perform a:

ros2 list topics
or even
ros2 list nodes

You may find that they are still "active".